# Cutkosky rules for unstable fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

I have calculated a loop diagram with a virtual Delta Baryon. I have cut the diagram through this Delta Baryon using Cutkosky rules. So far, I have considered the Delta Baryon to be stable, but now I want to do the calculation for an unstable Delta. So instead of
$$\frac{(\gamma^\mu p_\mu +m) (-g_{\rho\nu}+\frac{1}{3}\gamma_\rho\gamma_\nu)}{p^2-m^2}$$ my propagator now looks like this:
$$ \frac{1}{Z_2} \frac{-g_{\rho\nu}+\frac{1}{3}\gamma_\rho\gamma_\nu}{\gamma^\mu p_\mu - \bar{m}} $$
with
$$ \bar{m}=m-i\frac{\Gamma}{2Z_2}$$
and
$$ Z_2 = 1-\Sigma'(m).$$
$\Sigma'(m)$ is the derivative of the self energy with respect to $m$. In the stable case I replaced the denominator by $-2\pi i \delta(p^2-m^2)$. How do I do this now? Doing the same for the unstable case would result in an imaginary momentum.